# Writing a function to check if a relational statement is true or false

Tags: c, function, logic, rational-number

Here is the function (I hope the logic is fairly obvious).

Let x be one of the '<' or '>' operators
and a and b are the terms.

```
int rationalCheck(x, a, b){

    if ( x == '<' && a < b && b < a ){
        printf( "a is less than b\n" );
    }

    if ( x != '>' && a > b && b > a ){
        printf( " a is greater than b\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input into the function would be

```
(4 < 4) > (3 > 3)
```

This would evaluate to

```
(4 < 4) > (3 > 3) is false
```

Or input into the function would be

```
(4 < 6) > (2 > 1)
```

This would evaluate to

```
(4 < 6) > (2 > 1) is true
```

Comment: and what do you find to be your problem?

Comment: Notice that in *C* or *C++*  you have `false < true`

Comment: `a < b && b < a` is false, also `a > b && b > a` is false

Comment: Your function only compares two numbers (numbers? Where are the parameter types?) - do you want a full-blown expression parser?

Comment: Note that in C, the expression `(4 < 6) > (2 > 1)` evaluates to 0 (false).  `4 < 6` is true, so it evaluates to 1; `2 > 1` is true and also evaluates to 1; therefore, the middle operator is evaluating `1 > 1` which is false and evaluates to 0.

Comment: Sorry, the logic is not obvious at all. Bothe of the conditions are always false, so the function always returns 0. `a < b && b < a` and `a > b && b > a` evaluate to 0 or false whatever the variables a and b hold. It doesn't matter what else is in the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass operators/operations to functions in C. I suggest considering Haskell.

Alternatively, you *can* pass operations to *macros*, so this can be implemented as a macro, hence the definition of the `assert` macro being something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define assert(cond) if (!(cond) && printf("Assertion failed: " # cond " at " __FILE__ ":%d\n", __LINE__) != 0) abort()

int main(void) {
    assert(1 > 1);
}
```

Perhaps you want something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define rational_check(cond) printf(# cond " is %s\n", (cond) == 0 ? "false" : "true")

int main(void) {
    rational_check((4 > 4) > (3 > 3));
    rational_check((4 < 6) > (2 > 1)); // (4 < 6) > (2 > 1) is 1 > 1, by the way... false
}
```

I can't be certain, however, whether this suits your needs. A function pointer can't be derived from rational_check, and it can't work with strings that represent expressions formed during runtime; You'd need to write a translator for any use cases that require those... Otherwise, this should be suitable.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I was over thinking it.

```
int rationalCheck(x, a, b){


if ( x == '<')
{
    if (a >= b)
    {
        return 99;
    }

    if (b <= a) {
        return 99;
    }
}

if (x == '>')
{
    if (a <= b)
    {
        return 99;

    }
    if (b >= a)
    {
        return 99;
    }

}


return 1;
}
```

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Please learn to write in C89 at least.  A function written like that with no types for the parameters at all is appallingly antiquated.  Such code would not be acceptable in industry.  It was barely tolerable before the original C standard was published; it certainly isn't acceptable in modern C.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you think your second `return 99;` will be executed?  There are none I can think of! Similarly with the fourth.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler willing to learn here. Could you offer feedback with a code example?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also thanks for pointing out the second return will never run! \

Comment: The function should be defined with types for the arguments (in prototype notation) such as: `int rationalCheck(char x, int a, int b) { ... }`.  The implicit `int` notation you were using is not part of standard C99 (though compilers still recognize it, usually with generating a warning).  You aren't using Turbo C are you, by any mischance?  If you're using GCC, using the `-Wall` option is a good starting point.